# Почему таблетки пьют?

Tags: лексика

Совершенно привычная нам фраза: "Выпить таблетку".
Понятно, когда требуется выпить микстуру, настойку или еще что-нибудь жидкое. Я понимаю, что таблетку чаще всего запивают водой, но не всегда. И, тем не менее, мы говорим именно "выпить таблетку", а не "проглотить" и т.д.
Почему так?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, запиваем же. А как надо – съесть таблетку? Звучит хуже. Проглотить? То же самое. Поэтому и есть нейтральное "принять" и разговорное "выпить" (чаще всего).